# how to color form Gradually from yellow to green

Tags: c#, winforms

how to color form on winform using C# Gradually from yellow to green ?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  this.DoubleBuffered = true;
  this.ResizeRedraw = true;
}

protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e) {
  using (var lgb = new LinearGradientBrush(this.ClientRectangle, Color.Yellow, Color.Green, LinearGradientMode.Vertical))
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(lgb, this.ClientRectangle);
}
```

Comment: That flickers like a cheap motel.  Override OnPaintBackground() instead.

Comment: ResizeRedraw = true to fix the resize problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the draw event of the form. Make sure you double buffer to reduce flashing. Then draw a rectangle with a `LinearGradientBrush`.

This should get you started.

http://weblogs.asp.net/cfrazier/archive/2005/08/10/422179.aspx

Comment: +1 But some code would help I assume. I don't get the feeling the OP knows how to do that